# How to use OpenOffice Spreadsheet to get an image from an excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, vb6, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a code that exports image from excel into a picturebox and here it is.

```
 Dim appExcel As Object



        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appExcel.Visible = False
        Dim xlsBook  As New excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsSheet As New excel.Worksheet

        Dim rowlocation As Integer
        Dim columnlocation As Integer
        Dim celladdress As String



        Set xlsBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Text1.Text)
        Set xlsSheet = xlsBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Dim x As excel.Shapes



        For Each x In xlsSheet.Shapes
            x.Copy
            Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
            Text2.Text = x.Name
            rowlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Row
            columnlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Column
            celladdress = xlsSheet.Cells(x.BottomRightCell.Row + 1, x.TopLeftCell.Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(celladdress)
        Next

    End If
```

and unfortunately this code wont work on my friends PC becuase he does not have an Excel installed but he has OpenOffice spreadsheet. I tried to open the Excel in Openoffice then the file opens now my goal is how can i convert the code above in OpenOffice? I mean run the code for OpenOffice files.

This is my code but its not working

```
   Dim objServiceManager As Object
    Dim objDesktop        As Object
    Dim objDocument       As Object
    Dim objText           As Object
    Dim objCursor         As Object
    Dim oDoc              As Object
    Dim ARG()
    Dim oGraph    As Object
    Dim oView     As Object
    Dim oDrawPage As Object
    Dim oSheet    As Object
    Dim Image     As System_Drawing.Image
    Dim oimage As Object
    Dim osize As Object

    Set objServiceManager = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
    Set objDesktop = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
    Set oDoc = objDesktop.loadComponentFromURL("file:///C:\Users\paul\Desktop\Testing.ods", "_blank", 0, ARG())
    Set oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    Set oGraph = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")
    Set oView = oDoc.CurrentController
    Set oDrawPage = oView.getActiveSheet.DrawPage


    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = 0 To 9
           ' Form1.Image1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData

            Form1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(oDrawPage)
        Next
    Next
```

TYSM for future help

This is the latest code in VB6 and it has an error saying vnd.sun.star is missing

```
 Dim objServiceManager As Object
    Dim objDesktop        As Object
    Dim objDocument       As Object
    Dim objText           As Object
    Dim objCursor         As Object
    Dim oDoc              As Object
    Dim ARG()
    Dim oGraph      As Object
    Dim oView       As Object
    Dim oDrawPage   As Object
    Dim oSheet      As Object
    Dim Image       As System_Drawing.Image
    Dim oimage      As Object
    Dim osize       As Object
    Dim Cell        As Object
    Dim sGraphicUrl As String
    Dim oDisp
   Dim oFrame
    Dim opos        As Object



    Set objServiceManager = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
    Set objDesktop = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
    Set osize = objServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Size")
    Set opos = objServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Point")
    Set oDoc = objDesktop.loadComponentFromURL("file:///C:\Users\paul\Desktop\ACE Express - Fairview_Sample PC of Gondola.ods", "_blank", 0, ARG())
    Set oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    Set oimage = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")
    Set oView = oDoc.CurrentController
    Set oDrawPage = oView.getActiveSheet.DrawPage
    Set oimage = oDrawPage.getByIndex(0)
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(oimage.GraphicURL)
```

Here is the output of the unzip picture

[image]

Comment: More of this question is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927324/how-to-use-openoffice-spreadsheet-to-get-an-image-from-an-excel-file.

Comment: Some of this question is also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986697/openoffice-error-vnd-sun-star-graphicobject.

Comment: Yes sir thats me, Sir Please help me to convert this to VB6 :( TYSM for help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what your code does, because I normally do not use Microsoft Office.  However it looks like this task can be accomplished using OpenOffice Basic.  One of the best places to learn OpenOffice Basic is [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).

To start with, look at section `5.9.5. Convert all linked images`.

**EDIT**:

To do this in Calc, first I went to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Dialogs` and created a dialog named "ImageViewerForm" with an image control named "MyImageControl".

Then I went to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> OpenOffice Basic` and added the following code:

```vb
Sub ShowImageViewerDialog
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oDlg = CreateUnoDialog(DialogLibraries.Standard.ImageViewerForm)
    oControl = oDlg.Model.MyImageControl
    oDrawPage = oDoc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)
    oImage = oDrawPage.getByIndex(0)
    oControl.ImageURL = oImage.GraphicURL
    oDlg.execute()
End Sub
```

To run the code, go to `Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro`.  Here is the result:

[image]

The "Next Image" button should be fairly straightforward to implement by adding an event handler.

For documentation, see [GraphicObjectShape](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/GraphicObjectShape.html) and [UnoControlButtonModel](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/UnoControlButtonModel.html).  But mostly I just used the [MRI tool](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool) to figure it out.

**EDIT 2**:

Regarding the error you posted, the `GraphicURL` property in this case is a string that references an in-memory object, not a filepath.  An example of the string is shown here:  https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/graphic/XGraphicObject.html.

So it is not suitable for passing to [LoadPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264946(v=vs.60).aspx), which takes a filename.

Perhaps you can get the actual image data from [oImage.Bitmap](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XBitmap.html) or oImage.Graphic.  Use MRI to see what attributes are available.

For example, it looks like there is a getDIB() method that might work like this:

```vb
Form1.Image1.Picture = oImage.Bitmap.getDIB()
```

One more idea: Instead of using an Office application, you could write code that unzips the file and reads each image in the Pictures subdirectory.

Comment: Sir thanks for the effort and im almost half away in figuring it out, my problem now is how to get the image from the spreadsheet into the picturebox?

Comment: Sir what where did you do this? Did you do this on Macro or VB6?

Comment: This is what I needed sir but it must be done in VB6

Comment: Sir based on your Edit 2 i get an error of Object Required

Comment: SIr pls see the edited post and I added the image of the unzip that your saying and I hope sir we stick on this code format because we came so far  and im sure a lot of new programmers will get a benefit from here. TYSM for patients and cooperation.

Comment: So instead of connecting to OpenOffice, can you use those .jpg files as arguments to LoadPicture?  Anyway yes, it does sound like the other approach might be close to working, but I cannot test it to see what exactly is needed.  So you'll need to try the different attributes to see what works.

Comment: If i do it sir all of the efforts that we made will be lost and honestly speaking I dont know how to do what you said make a code that will zip/unzip file and rename them? actually sir the point that i will do this is because each image has there own name below them so next is when we load the image  in picturebox I will do a for loop so all image in the spreadsheet will be get and i will also display there names below each image. Sir pls bear with me.

Comment: Ok, well now it's up to you to see if one of the attributes or methods shown by MRI or the documentation will work. Have you installed an object introspection tool such as MRI?

Comment: Install? You mean add reference sir? No sir i didnt do any installation between vb6 and openoffice what i only did is only codings

Comment: By "installing," I meant downloading and adding the MRI extension from the link in my answer.  The tool displays information about the methods and attributes of any UNO object.

Comment: Ok sir I think it will be the last of our discussion about this but still looking forward for your help soon. I want to figure this out not just on my own but also for others and in addition sir i see this link that points about my error about the `vnd.sun.star` it looks like the error is the ID of the image I hope there is a way that will get the ID and convert it or get the image and display it. anyways sir pls receivie my bounty as token of appreciation but still sir I will not accept this as answer and by the way sir I will stick on this code. TYSM and Sorry

Comment: Sir based on the link my error exaplain that `The numeric portion of the url is formed from UniqueID. As long as at least one instance of XGraphicObject with a particular UniqueID exists, the associated image/graphic is available.`

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but [according to the docs](https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html) you can control Open Office through COM automation.

Your VB6 code above is controlling Excel through COM automation. You could install Open Office on your machine, and see whether you can automate Calc from VB6 to open a spreadsheet and extract an image. I don't know whether it allows that. Excel COM automation is very powerful and allows you to do almost anything, Open Office may not be as powerful (I don't know).

I would advise thinking carefully about what problem you are trying to solve and whether there's another approach entirely!

Comment: Actually there 2 users of the system the first one uses excel they are creating a format in excel and send it in user 2 but the user 2 has only openoffice the good thing is that the excel can be open in open office but my code above will work if the user 2 will have excel but they are not using it my goal is how can i convert the code above so it can import excel without installing excel app

Comment: You can't "import Excel" unless Excel is installed. You might be able to "import Open Office", that's what my answer is about. See the [link](https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html). Alternatively transfer the picture or "format" from user 1 to user 2 without using excel files. If user 2 doesn't have Excel, it might be better to use another format.

Comment: Sir thanks for the effort and im almost half away in figuring it out, my problem now is how to get the image from the spreadsheet into the picturebox?