# OpenOffice Error vnd.sun.star.GraphicObject

Tags: image, vb6, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am trying to display an image from a SpreadSheet(OpenOffice) into my PictureBox control and here is my code.

```
Dim objServiceManager As Object
Dim objDesktop        As Object
Dim objDocument       As Object
Dim objText           As Object
Dim objCursor         As Object
Dim oDoc              As Object
Dim ARG()
Dim oGraph    As Object
Dim oView     As Object
Dim oDrawPage As Object
Dim oSheet    As Object
Dim oimage    As Object
Dim osize     As Object
Dim Cell      As Object
Dim GraphURL As String

Set objServiceManager = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
Set objDesktop = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
Set osize = objServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Size")
Set opos = objServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Point")
Set oDoc = objDesktop.loadComponentFromURL("file:///C:\Users\paul\Desktop\ACE Express - Fairview_Sample PC of Gondola.ods", "_blank", 0, ARG())
Set oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
Set oimage = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")
Set oView = oDoc.CurrentController
Set oDrawPage = oView.getActiveSheet.DrawPage
Set oControl = oDoc
Set oDrawPage = oDoc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)
Set oimage = oDrawPage.getByIndex(0)

Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(oimage.GraphicURL)
```

But sad to say I have this error

[image]

It is supposed to be that the image that will replace the image in my picturebox(Mountain.jpg) is this.

[image]

But it doesn't happen

Please take note of the following:

- The spreadsheet used is OpenOffice Calc
- Displaying the image inside Picturebox (VB6)

**Update 2**
The error comes from  the code.

`Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(oimage.GraphicURL)`

Comment: The integrated program language for Calc is OpenOffice Basic (also called Star Basic).  Your post is tagged VB6, which is a different language.   Are you programming from some kind of external platform?

Comment: Yes sir I am using VB6 program to control Open Office can you help me with this one? if its ok with you. TYSM.

Comment: I take a look at your profile for a minute and I see that your posts are related in openoffice. Looking forward to have a convo. with you about this issue today TYSM

Comment: I do not have experience with VB6, unfortunately.  To help those who are more familiar you probably need to list which line of code is triggering the error.  You might also look into object analysis tools like xray (from the webpage of [Bernard Marcelly](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html)) to check what properties and methods your object `Image1` has.